# "Sounds like" query in Google

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine

"Sounds like" based on Soundex or Metaphone is not uncommon option for proprietary full text search in databases ( Oracle, MS SQL Server ) or open source search engines such as Lucene.
I have a difficulty using Google :)  to find out whether anything similar does exist for advanced Google search. Regarding wildcard  search it seems to be implied only  ( by stemming which doesn't always produce everything we want as if it were a wildcard ) , but what about "sounds like". Is anything similar available only at Google App level , but not at Google website itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a spell-checking algorithm, which includes sounds-like, typos, and common misspellings. It usually shows the corrected spelling as the "Did You Mean" link at the top of the results page, and sometimes it automatically shows the search results of the suggested spelling as well, as in: http://www.google.com/search?q=haskel+programing+language.